# assembleDebug not working with Gradle2.4 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to use gradle-2.4.
Here is my new updated `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
#Sun Dec 21 21:28:27 GMT+05:30 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

After this update I ran the clean command so that it used 2.4 and 2.2.1 (the older version).

Now, if I use `./gradlew assembleDebug` command in Android studio, it throws the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ActiveAndroid:compileDebugTestAidl'.
> Executor Singleton not started

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

But if I run the same command on command line, it works.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It might be an issue with the Gradle daemon. Try restarting Android Studio and/or killing all Gradle related processes on your machine.

Comment: Same problem. Worked up to 2.3.

Comment: try `./gradlew --stop` to stop gradle daemon. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem. What I did to solve it

- kill all android studio via task manager (closing all instances should be enough)
- Manually deleted
- .gradle, .idea, build, YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.iml from the **ROOT DIR**
- inside the **app folder** deleted app.iml, build
- Reimport my project and let gradle rebuild it's settings and download the new version of gradle

I am pretty certain some of the above steps are not needed, but I did them just for the good measure.

Also I see really no gain by using 2.4. They promissed 20-40% faster builds... in your dreams, it didn't change anything for me :/

Comment: didnt work.. tried killing all possible processes, restarted machine but every now and then it stops working again.

Comment: Then I don't know how to help. Gradle 2.4 is working ok for us so far, but we a disappointed since they promised a lot faster builds - the reason why we bothered with updating it anyway, but sadly we are experiencing the same build times.

Comment: Also did you try to do other steps I mentioned, you have told me you killed studio and restarted the machine

Comment: Also delete your .gradle folder from your user's folder

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this happened when I started using the Gradle daemon. If I removed the --daemon option (or disabled it in IDEA/Studio's Gradle settings) then the problem went away.

Haven't looked into what's actually causing it yet, or how to use the daemon and not run into this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem every time I open or create a new project.
I searched through many posts and the only thing that worked so far is run the following command line inside the project folder:

gradlew -d assembleDebug

The down side is that it increases the size of the project folder up to 10mb, but it works.